# Core Data Returns incorrect value (although nearly right)

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

Okay so I ask the Core Data for a record (userKey), in that record is a PublicKey which I am extracting, however, publicKey ends up being 90% right but has a few extra characters at the beginning and is encapsulated in brackets.

I think my problem is I am getting a pointer rather than the data from the userMatches.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
AppDelegate *appdelagate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
context = [appdelagate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"KeyData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userKeyCD = %@", userKey];
[request setEntity:entitydesc];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

userMatches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSString *publicKey = [userMatches valueForKey:@"publicKeyCD"];
```

Comment: I have checked the DB on the simulator and the value is correct there.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code (except that you're not checking the return value from `executeFetchRequest`, you're just assuming it worked). How did that value get into the data store in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  Yes at the moment all I have is NSLogs for the errors (I edited them out), the error is (null).

Comment: You are not setting the entity of the fetch request. How can this even work remotely?

Comment: Yes you are right, I have changed.  The Entity was setup in my code I just managed to cut it out when copying to here (there was lots of comments and stuff too) - sorry this was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I changed the last line to this and it worked fine;

```
    NSString *publicKey = [[userMatches objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"publicKeyCD"];
```

I did not show how it was defined but userMatches is an NSArray (sorry). It is used in a similar way further up the code;

```
   NSArray *userMatches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Now I think about it is an array the right type?